# angularjs ui-view element not rendering content

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes, angularjs-routing, angular-ui-router

I'm following [this](https://thinkster.io/mean-stack-tutorial/) tutorial to get familiar with the `MEAN` stack. I got to the point where they start using a routing configuration using `ui-router`. I've set everything up like they have it, but my page isn't rendering anything in my `<ui-view>` element.

(this was working before I added the routing config)

Here's what my files look like:

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Flapper News</title>
  <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.10/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.10/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
  <script scr="indexHomeState.js"></script>
  <script src="indexController.js"></script>
  <script src="postsService.js"></script>
  <style> .glyphicon-thumbs-up { cursor:pointer } </style>
</head>
<body ng-app="flapperNews">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
      <ui-view></ui-view>
    </div>
  </div>


    <script type="text/ng-template" id='/home.html'>
      <div class="page-header">
        <h1>Flapper News</h1>
      </div>

      <div ng-repeat="post in indexCtrl.getPosts() | orderBy:'-upvotes'">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"
          ng-click="indexCtrl.incrementUpvotesForPost(post)"></span>
        {{post.upvotes}}
        <span style="font-size:20px; margin-left:10px;">
          <a ng-show="post.link" href="{{post.link}}">
            {{post.title}}
          </a>
          <span ng-hide="post.link">
            {{post.title}}
          </span>
        </span>
      </div>

      <form ng-submit="indexCtrl.addPost()"
        style="margin-top:30px;">
        <h3>Add a new post</h3>

        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text"
            class="form-control"
            placeholder="Title"
            ng-model="indexCtrl.title"></input>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text"
          class="form-control"
          placeholder="Link"
          ng-model="indexCtrl.link"></input>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Post</button>
      </form>
    </script>


</body>
</html>
```

routingConfig (indexHomeState.js)

```
angular.module('flapperNews')
.config('indexHomeState', indexHomeState);


indexHomeState.$inject = ['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider'];

function indexHomeState($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $stateProvider
    .state('home', {
        url: '/home',
        templateUrl: '/home.html',
        controller: 'indexController as indexCtrl'
    });
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('home');


}
```

my angular app/controller declaration:

```
angular.module('flapperNews', ['ui.router'])
.controller('indexController', indexController);

indexController.$inject = ['postsService'];

function indexController(postsService) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.test = 'Hello world';

    vm.getPosts = postsService.getPosts;
    vm.addPost = postsService.addPost(vm.title, vm.link);
    vm.incrementUpvotesForPost = postsService.incrementUpvotesForPost;

}
```

post service

```
angular.module('flapperNews')
.factory('postsService', postsService);

function postsService() {
    var serv = this;
    var posts = [
      {title: 'post 1', upvotes: 5},
      {title: 'post 2', upvotes: 2},
      {title: 'post 3', upvotes: 15},
      {title: 'post 4', upvotes: 9},
      {title: 'post 5', upvotes: 4}
    ];
    function getPosts() {
        return posts;
    }
    function addPost(title, link) {
        if(!title || title === '') { return; }
        posts.push({
            title: vm.title,
            link: vm.link,
            upvotes: 0
        });
        vm.title = '';
        vm.link = '';
    }
    function incrementUpvotesForPost(post) {
        post.upvotes ++;
    }
    return {
        getPosts: getPosts,
        addPost: addPost,
        incrementUpvotesForPost: incrementUpvotesForPost
    }

}
```

Comment: Any console errors? have you added `postsService` to your  `angular.module('flapperNews')` ?

Comment: @PankajParkar yea I'll post the rest of the code

Comment: please do post error too.so that would help to find the direction to solve it..

Comment: @PankajParkar theres no error. There's just nothing displaying

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks good only the thing you are missing is, you need to change

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('home');
```

to

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
```

Also you have misspelled the `src` to `scr` for `indexHomeState.js`, That restricting your JS files from loading

**Scripts**

```
<script src="indexController.js"></script>
```

As you don't have `indexHomeState` provider in your app, you shouldn't add `indexHomeState` as a string inside config block.

```
angular.module('flapperNews')
  .config('indexHomeState', indexHomeState);
```

It would be simply

```
angular.module('flapperNews')
  .config(indexHomeState); //removed `'indexHomeState',` from config
```

[**Demo Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/iyLjJEl8jBMQNLWnSTwH?p=preview)

Comment: let me try the source thing

Comment: @AbdulAhmad also updated answer with one more mistake with `config` block..and do look at plunkr for further query

Comment: thank you for the plunkr, I'm looking at it now and comparing with my code!!

Comment: @AbdulAhmad Glad to help you..Thanks :)